# Extract numbers from strings using regexpressions

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Hi i am new to javascript ,I want to extract numbers from String .

Ex: i want to buy a phone between 10000 to 20000

```
message = message.replace(/ /g, '')
var start_num = message.match(/\d+/g)[0];
var end_num = message.match(/\d+/g)[1];
```

this gives 10000 and 20000

```
I want to buy a phone between 10k and 20k
```

I have to extract 10k and 20k exact match . Please give regexp for that.

Comment: that's simple :- `\d+k?`..and again you will need regex for decimal numbers..

Comment: tq, sorry i forgot '?' after k.

Answer (score 2):

This help you :

```
var patt = /\d+k?/gi;
```

example :

```html
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
         <script>
             var i=0;
             var patt = /\d+k?/gi; //if want only 1000k and no 1000 so remove '?'
             var str = "I want to buy a phone between 10k and 20k";
             alert(str.match(patt));
             
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please  tell me for exact match for 10k ?

Comment: @Voora Tarun , you want exact only 10k?

Comment: not like that, exact matches in entire sentence, It should match '10k' and '20k' ,

Comment: @VooraTarun , You mean is  patt = /(10)k | (20)k/gi;  ??????? this only match 10k and 20k .